# Why doesn't the C++11 chrono library implement date?

Tags: c++, date, c++11, c++-chrono

We still have to deal with structures like `time_t` or `tm`.
`chrono` is really conveniently designed for computing time intervals. But `time_point`... Is it so hard to implement direct access to year, month, day and etc and formatted print? For example:

```
void print_date(std::chrono::time_point<std::chrono::system_clock> tp){
    time_t raw_time = system_clock::to_time_t(tp);
    tm* time_info = localtime(&raw_time);

    char date[20] = {};
    strftime(date, 20, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", time_info);

    cout << date;
}
```

I think that many programmers write something similar.
There probably was a serious reason for this design. But what might that reason be?

Comment: Not having calendar functionality is probably a good **separation of concerns**. It's very difficult to do calendar functionality properly, e.g. Boost has two different calendar sub-libraries, and neither is very easy or natural to use IMHO.

Comment: You can use http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time instead of `strftime`.

Comment: `chrono` is good for what it does - managing timers and time intervals. NOT dates and / or local time.

Comment: Looks like a `“______ sucks, am I right?”`: http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Comment: @mikedu95, yeah, I confess, edit in few seconds:)

Comment: @mikedu95: the question itself is not a bad one, it was just poorly asked. I've edited it, think it has a chance now.

Comment: @VioletGiraffe, thank you very much:)

Comment: Indeed, the edit version is more constructive so I have canceled my downvote :)

Comment: Another point is that time intervals are fairly objective and universal, while date is locale-specific -- there are many different calendars used to determine the date, and some of them vary from country to country.

Comment: http://howardhinnant.github.io/date_v2.html builds on top of `<chrono>`

Comment: Here is a video introduction of Howard Hinnant's date library linked to in TemplateRex's comment above: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tzyGjOm8AKo